# Rails 3 and HTML escape from within helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From one ERB view, I have this helper call:

```
<p><%=progress @object.progress %></p>
```

This is the helper method (I've simplified it):

```
def progress(value)
    s = content_tag(:span, "pre:")
    s += " <strong>#{value} %</strong>"
    return s.html_safe
end
```

It seems that if you merge those two types of HTML strings, the latest part is not rendered properly. You'll see this:

```
pre: <strong>40 %</strong>
```

---

If you combine the strings like so:

```
def progress(value)
    s = content_tag(:span, "pre:")
    s += content_tag(:strong, " #{value} %")
    return s.html_safe
end
```

everything work!

Comment: Please, provide more info. E.g. show us example "not working HTML".

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I mean that HTML gets escaped and rendered as string. Check out the latest edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String returned from `content_tag` is marked as `html_safe`, when you add other unsafe string it's escaped before concat.

Here's a nice explanation on how the SafeBuffers (the class that does the html_safe magic) work: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/

Answer (score 1):

I think, it's happened, because string returned from `content_tag` marked as `html_safe`. So, if you try to add something to this string, it's automaticly escaped.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using first example then add **to_s** for a type transformation.